# Grand Central Dispatch. How to run one async group, wait, then run another, wait again, then finish?

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

Below is a sample function where I try to run one main group, wait, then run two other background tasks on separate threads, wait, then return a value altered in the general blocks shown below.  What is shown below is my guess at how to do this.  It works if I run these blocks all in one block.  It fails when I separate the blocks.  Does anyone have an example of how they accomplish something similar?  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
-(NSString *)sampleFunction:(NSString*)inputString
{
 __block NSString *returnString;

 dispatch_group_t mainGroup = dispatch_group_create();
 dispatch_group_t otherGroup = dispatch_group_create();

 void (^firstBlock)(void) = ^(void)
 {
  ...
 };

 void (^secondBlock)(void) = ^(void)
 {
  ...
 };


 void (^thirdBlock)(void) = ^(void)
 {
  ...
 };

 dispatch_group_async(oneGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), firstBlock);

 dispatch_group_wait(oneGroup, sizeof(int));

 dispatch_group_async(otherGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), secondBlock);
 dispatch_group_async(otherGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), thirdBlock);

 dispatch_group_wait(otherGroup, sizeof(int));

 dispatch_release(userGroup); 
 dispatch_release(otherGroup);

 return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the big picture, what are you trying to accomplish? I don't get the waiting part.

Comment: And why are you passing `sizeof(int)` as argument to `dispatch_group_wait`? You do know `DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER`?

Comment: Why not just execute all the code on the one thread? if you are waiting for the threads to finish, then what's the point of even having the threads?

Comment: I am executing these things on separate threads, because there are tasks that are run on the UI thread that will lock the user interface.  The first block needs to be populated before the second and third block can be run.  I pause the final time so I can return a value obtained from all the blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to do this, but the most conceptually simple (or at least obvious) way would be to create a group for each stage of your "pipeline", then have the completion callback for group A schedule the work on group B which also has a completion callback which schedules the work on group C.

The key here is not to actually "wait" for a group to complete - that's unnecessary. Groups can have completion blocks that will get run automatically when the last block in that group finishes (see dispatch_group_notify()), and this is a good way of creating "fan in" points where you've fanned out a bunch of work in the group.

Answer (score 7):

dispatch_semaphore is your friend here. :-)

```
/* Create your semaphore with 0 */
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

/* wait on the semaphore, causes your second & third queue to wait */
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

/* At the end of your first queue finishing, signal the semaphore waiting in 
   the 2nd queue to take over */
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
```

If you want an even simpler solution, just use dispatch_apply (it does the semaphore work for you) instead of these groups, though not exactly sure what you're using your groups for.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I will try this soon and get back to you with and up vote and correct answer when I am met with success :)